# End of Audio file in java

Tags: java

I have written this code for playing audio file, I want to get indication when my audio file ends after playing. I have tried   AS.getMicrosecondLength() == AS.getMicrosecondPosition()   but these methods are undefined for the AudioStream. Please tell how I can do that.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;


public class A {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {

        AudioStream AS = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("sounds.wav"));
        AudioPlayer.player.start(AS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be aware of `sun.audio`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031701/sun-audio-player-and-sound-i-o

Comment: You shouldn't being the sun.audio classes directly at all. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11919009/207421) for the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`AS.getMicrosecondLength() == AS.getMicrosecondPosition()` could be used to set off the flag when the clip has ended

Comment: These methods are undefined for AudioStream.