# Reading Audio file in java

Tags: java

I have written this code for playing audio file,and I want to get indication when my audio file ends after playing. I have tried `AS.getMicrosecondLength() == AS.getMicrosecondPosition()` but these methods are undefined for the AudioStream.

My Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;


public class A {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {

        AudioStream AS = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("sounds.wav"));
        AudioPlayer.player.start(AS);
    }
}
```

Please tell how I can solve my problem

Comment: [You really shouldn't be using any `sun.*` packages.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22031701/1079354)

Comment: Please tell the alternative

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11919009/207421) for the proper way to do it.