# Java - Lag when playing short audio clip frequently

Tags: java, audio, wav, clip

After some days of research on the internet, I came here looking for help. I'm currently developing a short 2D game for friends (and really just for fun), and I learned about Clips some days ago. In this game, the player can gather objects (almost like the coins in Mario). My problem is that I have a very short sound (~ 1 sec for 50kB) played when gathering a coin, and if the player gather let's say 3 coins in 1 second, then the Clip make the game lag. If the precedent Clip has ended, then there is no lag. But if the precedent Clip has not ended, then trying to play the Clip again make the game lag (very much).

I have a very small computer, not very powerful, but this problem is really annoying. I get the exact same problem with a sound when the player throws a weapon. I have a short clip, and if the player throws this weapon too fast, the game lag ...

Here is the things I already tried :

- Use an array of clips (of this same sound), and play a clip that is not currently playing
- Use different clips (of this same sound), and same as before
- Make multiple copies (of this same sound), and load it in different clips
- Make a separate thread for playing sounds, but I'm not comfortable at all with threads :/

But none of these change this problem ...

Now here is part of my code. First is the class that I use to load a sound into Clip.

```
package sound;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
// My own package
import utils.Utils;

public class SoundLoader {

public static Clip loadSound(String path) {
    Utils.log("Loading " + path + " ... ");

    try {
        URL url = SoundLoader.class.getResource(path);
        AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        AudioFormat format = audioIn.getFormat();

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(audioIn);

        Utils.log("success\n");
        return clip;
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Utils.log("failed !\n");
        return null;
    }
}   
}
```

Now is the class where I'll manage all sounds :

```
package sound;

import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
// My own package   
import principal.Handler;

public class SoundManager {

    private Clip woosh;
    private Clip coin1;
    private Clip coin2;

    public SoundManager(Handler handler) {
        woosh = SoundLoader.loadSound("/resources/sounds/woosh2.wav");
        coin1 = SoundLoader.loadSound("/resources/sounds/coin1.wav");
        coin2 = SoundLoader.loadSound("/resources/sounds/coin2.wav");
    }

    public void wooshClip() {
        startClip(woosh);
    }
    public void coin1Clip() {
        startClip(coin1);
    }
    public void coin2Clip() {
        startClip(coin2);
    }   
    public synchronized void startClip(Clip clip) {
        clip.stop();
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.start();
    }
    public void loopClip(Clip clip) {
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }
    public void stopClip(Clip clip) {
        clip.stop();
    }

}
```

And finally, when I want to play a Clip, I use the public method startClip() from my "Player" class (representing obviously the player).

`handler.getSoundManager().wooshClip();`

As I see my code, if the Clip is already playing, then the method starClip() should just stop it and replay it. Why is it lagging so much ? And why is it lagging even if I use different Clips ? What does make my game lag if I'm just stopping a Clip and replay it ?

I hope you will be able to help me ... It's rare that I don't find an answer on the web. If you need anything more to answer me just let me know !

Thanks for your time spent on this long question !

EDIT : I tried my game on a much powerful computer and there is absolutely no lag because of the audio clips ... But my question remains ! How could a 50kB clip make so much lag ?? I really don't understand the problem ...

**Solution**

I just discovered a solution while working on this project : now my entities that should play a sound when gathered by the player (like the sound of a coin in Mario) contain the audio clip of their "death". I don't understand exactly why it works now but it does ...

Comment: Can we look at your Clip class as well? Thanks.

Comment: It's not "my" class, it's the `javax.sound.sampled.Clip` class.

Comment: This guy uses almost the same code but without the stop() before the rewind(). Can you check if that does anything useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11980334/1319284

Comment: Without the `clip.stop()` it doesn't lag, but the clip plays 2 times when I gathered 8 coins, so ... it's playing like 1 time of 4 :/ and then it stops playing at all.

Comment: Just for funsies, try Clip.close(), and then re-load the clip

Comment: I tried it, I did `clip.close()` then `clip = SoundLoad.loadSound(path...)` then `clip.start()` but it's worse :/ thanks for your guesses, it's really appreciated !!

Comment: Try to play your sound from a different thread.

Comment: I tried `public class SoundManager implements Runnable`, then start this thread from my main game thread, but I got the same problem but I maybe did totally incorrectly ... I have to say that I'm really not comfortable with threads, I don't understand well if my "sound thread" stay alive after `run()` and if not, how to let it stay alive.
Again, thanks for your answers guys !

Comment: So my question would be : are threads the only way to get rid of this problem ? I mean ... it's a 50kB wav file ... not much indeed ... I would be insecure to be using threads as I don't understand them well. (I know the theory, but that doesn't help me much to understand them really).

Comment: The good news is, threads probably wouldn’t make a difference.  Sounds are already played asynchronously.

Comment: Do you get different results if you create your clip with `Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();`?

Comment: I can't do just that because I want my game to be distributed. That implies that my game will be a jar file, so I need to get the URL of my file, and then AudioInputStream. I can't just do `Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip()` (as I understand from what I found on the internet and from what I tried).
But I'm not sure what you mean there ... where would you me to put this line of code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`javafx.scene.media.AudioClip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) from JavaFX instead of `javax.sound.sampled.Clip`. AudioClip has lower latency.